# javascript: regex not printing escape character

Tags: javascript, regex, printing, escaping, character

I want to do a regex search this is my data.

```
a = 'Watch4net APG Event: Host/O:\ Label:OraDB Serial Number 1610f067 on Device dlpdb1 is alerted.'
```

Now I want to do the extraction as below.

```
rx = /Event: Host\/(.*) on/
arr = rx.exec(a)[1]
```

In the result I am getting the following

```
'O: Label:OraDB Serial Number 1610f067'
```

the backslash after the O:**** is getting missed. How can I print it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, it is not "getting missed", because **it is not there**. There is no literal ``\`` in your input string.

Comment: there is one backslash after O:

Comment: There is a backslash symbol after `O` in the *string literal*, but it is not denoting a literal ``\``. To denote a literal ``\`` in a string literal, you need ``\\``.

Comment: Again: you cannot "print" anything that is not present.

Comment: I got your point but the problem is I am getting this output from somewhere, and I need to find out the event type after Host till "on". So we cant ignore it.

Comment: down voter, if you dont understand complete problem please stop downvoting. Or atleast discuss with me before downvoting it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to find all backslashes in your data and replace them with a double backslash.

```
a = 'Watch4net APG Event: Host/O:\\ Label:OraDB Serial Number 1610f067 on Device dlpdb1 is alerted.'
```

Javascript is taking a single backslash as an escape character. Note that you won't be able to use javascript to double them up as it can't 'see' it to begin with, so will need to manipulate the data some other way.

Comment: Thanks for help t c, I have to this thing in a rhino engine. Can you suggest something?

Comment: It's pretty horrible and hacky (and I have no formatting options in this comment) but after the line arr = rx.exec(a)[1]; you could put arr = arr.replace(/([A-Z]:)/,'$1\\'); This will look for a capital letter followed by a colon and replace it with that capital letter followed by a colon followed by a backslash